# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>' when trying to async observe a datasource

Tags: angular, observable

I have this minimal component:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  private counter = 1;

  data$ = new Observable<number>((observer: Observer<number>) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(this.counter);
      this.counter++;
    }, 1000);
  });

  constructor() {}
}
```

And I'm trying to get the numbers asynchronously like:

`<div *ngFor="let d of data$ | async">{{ d }}</div>`

However I get the error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>'.`

To my understanding this is not that different from the angular heroes tutorials [HeroSearchComponent](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#herosearchcomponent).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ngFor directive used for iterating array of values. In your code you were using *ngFor to iterate a single primitive value, that's why you are getting this error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>'.`

If you want to get single value you can use ngIf along with async pipe

```
 <div *ngIf="data$ | async as d">{{ d }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's really obvious I know. Now I feel dumb again. :-D

Comment: You are welcome, It happens to everyone.. Happy learning 